# About duplicate question

Tags: discussion, feature-request, duplicate-questions

Many times it happens that what I want to ask is already present on this site so as per rule I cannot ask the same question again.

But what if accepted answer of an existing post doesn't solve my problem?

In this case I need to ask query about that answer or I need to explain my problem's situation but in this site asking question about your problem on others post is not allowed then what else can I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not "not allowed" to ask duplicate questions. The reason why duplicate questions are closed is that SO strives to be a canonical reference and knowledge base. In a knowledge base, you don't need a hundred entries about the same topic, all of varying quality. All you need is *one good entry* which answers the problem definitively. SO strives to work out that one canonical, definitive answer. Closing questions as duplicate serves this goal.

It follows that if the existing questions and answers do not in fact answer your question, then you have a new question. Post your new question, provide as much detail as possible about the situation and specifically *why* the existing answer doesn't work in your case. Consider adding a link to your new question from the old existing question if you think this improves the existing answers.

Example:

### Existing question

> Why does *foo* in *bar* not do *baz*?

#### Existing answer

> Because your *foo* is `blarg`, change it to `blorg` and it works.

### Your new question

> My *foo* in *bar* doesn't *baz*, even if I do change it to `blorg` as pointed out **in this other answer**. In my case there's also X, Y and Z, which I think are interfering. How to solve this?

Answer (score 4):

OK , You Can Ask new Question and describe the exact problem and also include existing question link and also describe that what is not full filling in that question's answer..

Comment: Yes I agree with you. Exactly what I did in my previous question then also my question is marked as duplicate that's why I posted this question.

Comment: @MohiniMhetre you don't have any questions that have any duplicate votes.  Which question are you referring to where this happened?

Comment: @psubsee2003 http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230907/what-can-i-do-to-get-out-of-a-question-ban-in-stack-overflow-site this question

Comment: @MohiniMhetre ah.. well, the rules are generally much different on meta sites (including MSE) than on the main sites.  The guidance in this answer is pretty good for a main site.

Comment: @MohiniMhetre On meta sites, especially with that specific question (as it is extremely common), there's not much anyone call really offer as an answer that makes it worth keeping the question open.  You will generally get more value in the feedback from the comments than in answers.